# Auto Animate Scroll to Right of an Element that Overflows its Container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, jquery-animate

I have a group of elements which fade in and out, (one after another), within a containing div (`.info`). Some of the elements stay within the container when they appear, while others overflow the container, which is not preferred.

When such a circumstance occurs, I would like for some kind of horizontal/auto-scroll effect to be applied, so it can reveal the beginning to the end of the overflowing text element, while still remaining on a single line. Is there any way to accomplish this with JQuery?

Here is a snippet of the progress I have made so far:

```js
(function() {
  var tab = $(".info .tab");
  var tabIndex = -1;

  function showNextTab() {
    ++tabIndex;
    tab
      .eq(tabIndex % tab.length)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(2000)
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextTab);
  }
  showNextTab();
})();
```

```css
.info {
  background: skyblue;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.info .tab {
  display: none;
}

h2.tab {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
  <h2 class="tab">This is the first line.</h2>
  <h2 class="tab">This is the second line.</h2>
  <h2 class="tab">This is the third line (which is longer than the first and second line.)</h2>
  <h2 class="tab">This is the fourth line (which is longer than the first, second, and third line.)</h2>
</div>
```

**UPDATE: Scroll Effect Added/Still Troubleshooting**

Here is an updated snippet, with recent recommendations applied:

```js
var myVar = "";

(function() {
  var tab = $(".info .tab");
  var tabIndex = -1;

  function showNextTab() {
    ++tabIndex;
    myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
    tab
      .eq(tabIndex % tab.length)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(2000)
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextTab);
  }
  showNextTab();
})();

function myTimer() {
  var leftPos = $(".info").scrollLeft();
  $(".info").animate({
    scrollLeft: leftPos + 200
  }, 800);
  myStopFunction();
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

```css
.info-wrap {
  background: skyblue;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.info {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info .tab {
  display: none;
}

h2.tab {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<duv class="info-wrap">
  <div class="info">
    <h2 class="tab">This is the first line.</h2>
    <h2 class="tab">This is the second line.</h2>
    <h2 class="tab">This is the third line (which is longer than the first and second line.)</h2>
    <h2 class="tab">This is the fourth line (which is longer than the first, second, and third line.)</h2>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**Question 1:** Why is the fourth `<h2 class="tab">` element not scrolling from the beginning? It seems to be starting from a halfway point, to the right.

**Question 2:** How can the speed of the slide-left animation be modified? I am trying to understand what the `myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);` is targeting, and also  `scrollLeft: leftPos + 200}, 800);`.

Answer (score 1):

**EXPLANATION:**

**Question1** : Because the width of scroll maximum is relative based on how many characters are created to make the width of scroll size. Right when the function is initialed, the variable `$('.info').scrollLeft()` seems save the previous point. Therefore, I re-initial that code by adding this code:

```
$(".info").animate({scrollLeft: 0}, 0); //$(.info) point = 0
```

**Question2** : The left side animation can be speed up by increasing the value of leftPos. And this `myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);` is to determine the start point. It means the function will begin at 1 sec.

Anyway here is the example below

```js
 

var myVar = "";

(function() {
  var tab = $(".info .tab");
  var tabIndex = -1;
  function showNextTab() {
    ++tabIndex;
    myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000); 
    tab
      .eq(tabIndex % tab.length)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(1000)
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextTab);
    $(".info").animate({scrollLeft: 0}, 0);
  }
  showNextTab();
})(); 
function myTimer() {
var leftPos = $('.info').scrollLeft();
$(".info").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 1500}, 800);
myStopFunction();
}
function myStopFunction() {
clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

```css
.info {
  background: skyblue;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow:scroll;
}

.info .tab {
  display: none;
}

h2.tab {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
  <h2 class="tab">This is the first line. testtesttesttesttesttesttttttttttt</h2>
  <h2 class="tab">This is the second line.</h2>
  <h2 class="tab">This is the third line (which is longer than the first and second line.)</h2>
  <h2 class="tab">This is the fourth line (which is longer than the first, second, and third line.)</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I guess I should have been more specific. When an element appears that overflows the container, I would like for that element to automatically scroll/or marquee to the right.

Comment: In a sense, it would animate the scroll on its own.

Comment: Ahh I see, I edited the answer tho. The script you're looking for is something like this setInterval(function () { 
var leftPos = $('.info').scrollLeft();
$(".info").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 200}, 800);
}, 800);
I am sorry for not paying attention

Comment: Thanks for the additional input! I have applied your suggestion to an updated snippet in my original question. I would appreciate if you would take a look at it, since I still have a few questions concerning the scrolling/panning right effect.

Comment: I edited the answer section to answer your few question concerning the scrolling/panning right effect. You are welcome, nrweb.